# Q: Including smarty variable in another variable

Tags: smarty, php-5.6

I have a smarty variable like this :

```
$var = "This is a test string";
```

That i assign to smarty :

```
$this->smarty->assign('variable', $var);
```

What I would want is to add a new smarty variable into my first one like this :

```
$var = "This is a test string with a new `$variable`";
```

But I don't know how to make this work,  I tried assigning both but when I call my $var in my smarty template it always display the $variable as text.

PS: I'm using smarty 3 if that can help.

Comment: It doesn't look as being related to Smarty at all. You need to learn about [variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in strings.

Comment: If it is a php code use $var = "This is a test string with a new {$variable}"; or $var = "This is a test string with a new".$variable; but I have no idea how you want to pass your new variable to php

Answer (score 0):

In smarty template (.tpl), after you assign variable to a view:

{$var = "This is a test string with a new "|cat:$variable}

now you can display this variable:

{$var}